# Percentiles: $F(x)$ or $\int f(x)$

Tags: statistics, percentile

When solving for percentiles with **cdf**, Should I discard constants?

From my book: $F(x_p) = P(X \le x_p) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_p} f(x) dx = \frac{p}{100}$

If I don't have the cdf formula, I can integrate the pdf $f(x)$ for $F(x)$, but there's the missing constant that the $F(x)$ might have had.

Example case:
cdf: $ F(x) = -\frac{4}{3x} + \frac{4}{3} $
pdf: $ f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} F(x) = \frac{4}{3x^2} $

Solving for median (50th percentile) using $F(x_m) = 0.5$:
$ F(x_m) = 0.5 = -\frac{4}{3x_m} + \frac{4}{3} $
$x_m = \frac{8}{5} $

Solving for median (50th percentile) using $\int_{-\infty}^{x_m} f(x) dx = 0.5$:
$ \int_{-\infty}^{x_m} f(x) dx = 0.5 = -\frac{4}{3x} |^{x_m} + C = -\frac{4}{3x_m} + C $
$ x_m = -\frac{8}{3} $

The answers I got are radically different, so either I am doing my math wrong, or the constant is shifting the answer a lot.

Comment: Remember that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}{F(x)}=1$. This pins down the constant.

Comment: Where does that constant come from? It is a definite integral.

Comment: One of my assignments said: Random var X has a CDF of $F(X)=\frac{A}{x} + B$, for $1 <= x <= 4$  
. We solved for A & B using the fact that $F(1) = 0$ and $F(4) = 1$. The constant came from solving those equations.